# SQL - Select pairs of users with different group ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write a query in SQL that returns pairs of users (name and surname) that are never associated together in the same group.

**GROUP**

```
idGroup
idUser (Foreign key)
```

**USER**

```
idUser (Primary key)
Name 
Surname
```

I tried this but it don't work, why?

```
SELECT u1.name, u1.surname, u2.name, u2.surname 
FROM group g1
JOIN group g2 ON g2.idgroup = g1.idgroup
JOIN user u1  ON u1.userid = g1.iduser
JOIN user u2  ON u2.userid = g2.iduser
WHERE g2.idgroup <> g1.idgroup
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Mureinik I'm using Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all it's just all two-users combinations except for those found in a group. We mainly have `MINUS`, `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` for this.

### MINUS

```
select u1.iduser, u2.iduser from "USER" u1 join "USER" u2 on u1.iduser < u2.iduser
minus
select g1.iduser, g2.iduser from "GROUP" g1 join "GROUP" g2 on g1.idgroup = g2.idgroup 
                                                           and g1.iduser < g2.iduser
```

### NOT IN

```
select u1.iduser, u2.iduser from "USER" u1 join "USER" u2 on u1.iduser < u2.iduser
where (u1.iduser, u2.iduser) not in
(
  select g1.iduser, g2.iduser from "GROUP" g1 join "GROUP" g2 on g1.idgroup = g2.idgroup 
                                                             and g1.iduser < g2.iduser
)
```

### NOT EXIST

```
select u1.iduser, u2.iduser from "USER" u1 join "USER" u2 on u1.iduser < u2.iduser
where not exists
(
  select null from "GROUP" g1 join "GROUP" g2 on g1.idgroup = g2.idgroup 
  where g1.iduser = u1.iduser
    and g2.iduser = u2.iduser
)
```

As you see, the three queries don't differ much. While the `MINUS` query looks simplest, it has the disadvantage that you cannot directly display the users' names, if you want to. `EXISTS` subqueries look always a tad more complicated than `IN` subqueries. (`NOT IN` holds a trap, though, when values can be null, which is not the case here.) My choice would be `NOT IN` here, but just pick what you like best.

(On a side note: `USER`  and `GROUP` are both SQL keywords and musthence not a good choice for table names in my opinion.)

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt fails because it just checks if the pair of users has at least one group not in common, while you want to check if *all* groups are distinct.

You can self-join the `users` table to generate all possible pairs of users, and then use `not exists` with an aggregate correlated subquery to ensure that no group exists where both users appear:

```
select u1.name name1, u1.surname surname1, u2.name name2, u2.surname surname2
from users u1
inner join users u2 on u1.id_user < u2.id_user
where not exists (
    select 1
    from groups g
    group by g.id_group
    having 
            max(case when g.id_user = u1.id_user then 1 end) = 1 
        and max(case when g.id_user = u2.id_user then 1 end) = 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the only thing I did not understand is the join condition for users and the use of the case ( how it works) (I have to study it, forgive me for these questions but I have just started studying SQL)

Comment: @Gwynbleidd: This is called conditional aggregation. We look per group (`group by g.id_group`). `case when g.id_user = u1.id_user then 1 end` is 1 for every row in the group where the user is user #1. So, `max(case when g.id_user = u1.id_user then 1 end)` is only 1 if at least one user in the group is user #1. The subquery checks whether there exists a group or not where both users we currently look at are in.

Comment: @Gwynbleidd: And as to `on u1.id_user < u2.id_user`: The idea is to join every user with every user. If we just crossed joined we would get (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), ... As we don't want to join a user with themselves, we'd join instead `on u1.id_user <> u2.id_user`. But then we would still get each pair twice: (1,2), (2,1), ... In order to avoid this we decide to replace `<>` with either `<` or `>`.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking `not exists`:

```
select u1.iduser, u2.iduser
from users u1 join
     users u2
     on u1.iduser < u2.iduser
where not exists (select 1
                  from usergroups ug1 join
                       usergroups ug2
                       on ug1.idgroup = ug2.idgroup
                  where ug1.iduser = u1.iduser and
                        ug2.iduser = u2.iduser
                 );
```

Comment: I am a neophyte, so forgive my questions. 
I have never seen a join condition done in this way (on u1.iduser < u2.iduser), what does it do specifically?

Comment: @Gwynbleidd . . . It might be simpler to think of it as `users u1 cross join users u2 where u1.iduser < u2.iduser . . . `.